# Why is Mos Espa in a big hole?

Tags: star-wars, the-book-of-boba-fett

In *The Book of Boba Fett*, much of the action takes place in the city of Mos Espa, previously seen in *The Phantom Menace* and *Attack of the Clones*. The version of it seen in the show has most of the city at the bottom of a large canyon or pit:

[image: Image of Mos Espa from The Book of Boba Fett]

As far as I know, this is the first time this version of Mos Espa has been seen. In the 2016 edition of *Complete Locations*, for example, Mos Espa is pictured as being built on a flat part of the desert. It also appears to be in the middle of the flat desert in *The Phantom Menace*, although the scenes we see could just take place on the outskirts above the cliff.

I'm guessing this was a creative decision made to visually distinguish Mos Espa from Mos Eisley, which parts of *The Mandalorian* take place in, but is there any official word about this choice? In-universe and out-of-universe explanations are both welcome.

Comment: [Screenrant discusses this](https://screenrant.com/book-boba-fett-mos-espa-tatooine-prequels-different/), but their article is just speculation.

Comment: If it was in a little hole there wouldn’t be enough space for all the buildings.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite "Hmm. Little hole or big hole?" "You idiot, big hole of course, otherwise we won't be able to handle expansion." *proceeds to expand outward from crater *

Comment: @PeterNielsen - Big hole, little hole, cardboard box.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Mos Espa was, according to the original artwork and concept design for *Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace*, always supposed to be portrayed as a city set *into* the desert. Essentially the goal was to replicate Luke's 'pit house' but on a city-sized scale.

Watto's Shop (and the events of the film) explicitly take place in the *outskirts* of the city, on the outer lip of the crater, hence why we don't see the dominating walls.

[image]

[image]
**<sub><sup>Images from [The Art of Star Wars: The Phantom Menace](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace)</sup></sub>**

Comment: Huh, TIL! I wonder if the later design of Utapau was influenced by this concept work.

Comment: @MiloP - Almost certainly. Everything in SW gets recycled

Comment: Must be a pain if it ever rains. I remember a similar pit city from the 2008 clone wars series, season 5 I think.

Comment: @User19087 - Luckily it never rains. Ever.

Comment: I presume there is some form of energy shielding that funnels sand storms away from the hole, otherwise be you'd spending your life sweeping up sand . . .

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - Luke's house had an electrostatic shield that stopped the sand coming in. I expect he still hated sand though. It's coarse and rough and irritating and it gets everywhere...

Comment: I'm sure "sand hating" is a family trait 

Comment: Tatooine has natural water in the ground and the air, and there's active wind currents, too. Therefore it _must_ rain on Tatooine at some point, even if it is a very rare occasion (like once every hundred years or something). Unless water also works "differently" in that galaxy far, far, away.

Comment: @TylerH, there's evidence that portions of the Atacama Desert here on Earth have gone at least 400 years without significant rainfall.

Comment: I think that "crater" refers to bowl-shaped depressions. This is like a reverse butte.

Comment: @TylerH - Worthy of asking [as its own question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259394/does-it-rain-on-tatooine)...

Comment: @Valorum: Apparently Luke **loved** sand.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: [Not according to what Luke said](https://screenrant.com/star-wars-luke-anakin-skywalker-sand-meme-marvel).

Answer (score 9):

A real world explanation for putting a desert city in a big hole would be to get more shadow and/or to get it out of the wind. (Although I have to admit, I have not seen those movies, so I have no idea what the climate in that area is supposed to be like)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question wasn't why _might_ a city be built like that, it was asking if the city had _always_ (in previous works) been intended to be depicted this way.

Comment: Yeah, I put too much emphasis on the last sentence... " In-universe and out-of-universe explanations are both welcome."

Comment: In the real world, they would be expending even more effort hauling wind-blown sand up and out of that giant crater.

Comment: If we speculate in 'real world' reasons that the city is in a pit, it could be due to extreme subsidence. Perhaps due to mining or a now depleted water reservoir. Mexico City for example is sinking quite severely: https://www.nap.edu/read/4937/chapter/4